# Ruby how to count the number of objects returned by yield

Tags: ruby, lambda

Currently I have a method that has a signature of such `time_in_intervals(from, till, interval, &block)` and I would like to be able to pass it a simple block that returns the count of number of objects yielded into the block.

My way currently looks like this

I have a function that declares an empty lambda

```
def empty      
  -> (x) {}
end
```

then I call my function with the empty lambda and count it

```
time_in_intervals('7AM', '8PM', 60, &empty) #=> Returns array of times
time_in_intervals('7AM', '8PM', 60, &empty).count #=> 14
```

is there any way to do this where I can pass it a more useful function then `&empty` something that would result in the count being returned without having to call `.count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you write this method? If so, change the definition of it to only `yield` if `block_given?`

Otherwise, if it strictly requires a block, you could do it this way by using the implicit block syntax:

```
(time_in_intervals('7AM', '8PM', 60) { }).count
```

Comment: Thanks, I did write this myself but I didn't know you could do optional blocks like that with `block_given`

Comment: `block_given?` will only return `true` if a block has been supplied. It's also not necessary or recommended to declare `&block` in your method signature unless you need to capture that block and pass it on to something else. Declaring it introduces some overhead that is only necessary if you need to do that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is analogous to the original with `.count` added to the end of the result. Putting that in the block changes the meaning completely.

Comment: For clarity: `(time_in_intervals(...) { }).count` is what's desired here.

Comment: Taxman, somehow I thought you were suggesting an empty block. It finally dawned on me that you meant it to be a representation of an arbitrary block. :-) I deleted my comments.